# Error with Jenkins executing weblogic.jar

Tags: jenkins, weblogic

I am using jenkins with windows 10 and weblogic. I created a pipeline to connect git, compile with maven and weblogic deploy. When run the command sh 'java weblogic.WLST script.py' i have the error :
Could not find or load main class weblogic.WLST"

But when a run this command in prompt windows, i dont have problems. I have the environment variables JAVA_HOME and   CLASSPATH.

Do I need to configure anything inside the jenkins to use this jar, weblogic.jar?

Comment: Try add the JAVA_HOME in Manage Jenkins => Global Properties => Environment variable

Comment: Hi,

thanks, i solved inserting CLASSPATH variable in Jenkins => Global Properties => Environment variable. To Windows OK, but in linux there is the same problem, the classpath dont solved. Any ideia